# How does & work in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, collections, syntax, iterator

How is the & used in rails when working with arrays, collections or ActiveRecord queries? Please provide examples and how it works.

So far I have seen implementations with common arrays but can't understand how it works. Below is a simple example, please use this to illustrate your answer.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

array.each do |number|
 number + 2
end
```

Comment: From your question it is unclear which use of `&` you are looking for. `&` is implemented as a set intersection operator on Array (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) but is also an alias for `to_proc` on Symbol (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) and is often used to write terse collection iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Ruby encounters a `&` before an object, it expects it to be a `Proc`, so it would call `to_proc` on this object.

So for example if you had

```
proc_object = proc{puts 1}
```

Passing `&proc_object` as an argument to a method that accepts a block would call to_proc on the object.

This is the same case with a symbol `:proc_object`, as a call to `&:method_name` is the same as doing `:method_name.to_proc.call`.

In an enumerable, objects are yielded to the proc, that is why you're able loop through an array object and print each element, because each of those elements are yielded during the loop.

For each element within the collection, the proc is called on them as such

```
[1,2,4,5].map(&:to_s) # => ['1', '2', '4', '5']
```

This basically converted each element of the array to a string object because each element of the array is yielded to my proc.

You should see the &:to_s executed within element's context e.g `5.to_s` because the method already exists within element's class etc.

If you were trying to achieve the same thing with a method that isn't defined on each element, you'd get an undefined_method error.

In your case, I don't think the it would be a good example unless a add_two method existed.

## Examples:

```
{dave: :fogo, stack: :overflow, day: :today}.map(&:first) # => would return :dave, :stack, :day because for each loop through the map, an array is yielded with the first element being the key and the second the value.

[1,2,3,5,10].map(&:even?) # => [false, true, false, false, true]
```

The array and hash is similar to ActiveRecord's, one thing to know is that the method you're passing must be defined within the class of the element.

I hope this makes sense.